# ConfigurationType error when using Entity Framework migrate.exe with multiple migration configurations

Tags: entity-framework

In my solution, I have a Data project that contains multiple Entity Framework 6.1.3 migration configuration classes. My goal is to run Entity Framework migration steps - for one of them, against an existing database - from TeamCity (or, to simplify, from a command line).

The migration configuration class I am using is the following:

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public partial class MyCustomMigrationConfiguration :
        DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyCustomContext>
    {
        public MyCustomMigrationConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\MyCustomContext\MigrationSteps";
        }
    }
}
```

I can successfully run the following command from Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

> Update-Database -Verbose -StartUpProject Web -ConnectionString '-my
>   connection string here-' -ConfigurationTypeName
>   MyCustomMigrationConfiguration -ConnectionProviderName
>   'System.Data.SqlClient'

I want to do the same thing from a command line, so I run this:

> migrate.exe MyProject.Data.dll "MyCustomMigrationConfiguration" 
>   /startUpConfigurationFile=MyProject.Web.dll.config 
>   /connectionString="-my connection string here-;" 
>   /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" /verbose

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR: The migrations configuration type
>   MyCustomMigrationConfiguration was not be found in the assembly
>   ‘MyProject.Data'.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, please?

Comment: Whre is the other part of the partial class defined? have you tried specifying it without quotes? Have you tried specifying the namespace qualified type name?

Comment: _Where is the other part of the partial class defined?_ 
I removed "partial" - still the same

_have you tried specifying it without quotes_ 
Yes, same result.

_Have you tried specifying the namespace qualified type name_ 
Yes, same result.

Comment: I thought you was running migrate.exe in the path where all the dependencies were available. You don't need to copy them, you can specify the folder where they are with a command line option. Please, see my answer. OTOH, as you state in your comment, as the error message is misleading you could open an issue in EF's codeplex site.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the directory where are all the dependencies (assemblies) needed to run your code. You can do that by using the `/startUpDirectory` option, [as explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx):

> Specify working directory
>
> `Migrate.exe MyApp.exe /startupConfigurationFile=”MyApp.exe.config” /startupDirectory=”c:\MyApp”`
>
> If you assembly has dependencies or reads files relative to the working directory then you will need to set startupDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (I ended up downloading the Entity Framework source code from http://entityframework.codeplex.com/ and debugging the migrate console application).

Apparently, all the dependencies of MyProject.Data.dll need to be copied in the same folder with it and migrate.exe, otherwise the Entity Framework migrate.exe tool will throw the misleading error message above.

Entity Framework could really use better error handling and a clearer error message in this case.

As a reference to Entity Framework devs: the following code in TypeFinder.cs was returning a null type because the dependencies of MyProject.Data.dll were not copied in the folder of migrate.exe:

```
type = _assembly.GetType(typeName, false);
```